# bash : multiple command on one line with different exit code

Tags: bash, command, exit

I run a `bash` command from a `c++` code using the `system` function provided
in `cstdlib`. My question is not about the `c++` implementation, but the one
thing that is relevant to my question, is that I have to run multiple command
on one line.

For instance, I run a gnuplot script contained in another directory. So my
command is the following:

```
cd some/path; gnuplot -e gnuplot_file.gp; cd - > /dev/NULL
```

Both `cd` commands are important for personal reasons. I also want to "hide" the ouput in `/dev/NULL`.

Here is my question : how do I know the exit status of the `gnuplot` command ?
Knowing if it failed is enough.

My problem is that I currently get the exit status of the last command, which
is true even if the `gnuplot` failed.

I know that if I use `&&` instead of `;`, the last command won't be executed if
the previous one fails and the exit status would then be false. But I need the last command to be executed...

What is the workaround ?

Comment: `cd some/path; gnuplot ...; eval 'cd -- "$OLDPWD";' [ "'${?#1}'" ]`

Comment: @mikeserv, thx a lot ! I wouldn't have found this by myself ! It looks ugly but it works !

Comment: @mikeserv Wouldn't `! [ "${?#0}" ]` make more sense?

Comment: @HaukeLaging - no, but it should be `${?##[!0]*}` actually, though that's pushing it and so `"[ $? -eq 0 ]"` would be more sensible. Anyway, the point is to evaluate to null a failed `$?` so that `[` returns true for a single, not-null arg or false for a single empty one.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - oh, yes! I'm sorry - i completely spaced the leading `!` there. I do that a lot - im a spacey guy i guess. i always have to look at the most simple things like 5 times before i actually get it. just a dummy that way, i guess. but yours is better.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, I'm not sure I understand the difference... I tried googling `! [ "${?#0}" ]` but as you may think, it's not very successful. What is this kind of thing called ?

Comment: @PinkFloyd Don't blame yourself. That's a quite unusual way to check the exit code (`$?`). Even I had to look at that for a while in order to get what it does. It treats the exit code as a string, removes the string `0`/`1` and checks whether something is left or whether the resulting string is empty. `[ "" ]` has exit code false. Independent of the string/number handling it is better to check for 0 than for 1 because 0 is the only success exit code but 1 is not the only error exit code.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, thanks ! but how does this catch the exit status of the second (gnuplot) command ? and not the third one (`cd` or `eval`) ? I get that it's better to look for 0. I then assume that this is what your version is doing : `! [ "${?#0}" ]`

Comment: @PinkFloyd `${?#1}` is in double quotes ("") not in single quotes ('') thus it is expanded as part of the `eval` command line i.e. before eval is executed and thus refers to the previous command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drop the `gnuplot` into a subshell and then it's the last command executed. You also no longer require the last `cd` because the change of directory at the beginning of the subshell affects only the `gnuplot`, and so the redirection to `/dev/null` is also moot.

```
( cd some/path; gnuplot -e gnuplot_file.gp )
```

Perhaps you intended the redirection to `/dev/null` to apply to the entire command? (That's not what you've written in your question, though.)

```
( cd some/path; gnuplot -e gnuplot_file.gp ) >/dev/null
```

Finally, my preference for a snippet like this would be to run the `gnuplot` only if the initial `cd` succeeded. This would affect the exit status, in that you'd get a *failed* return if the change of directory failed, but is probably safer code

```
( cd some/path && gnuplot -e gnuplot_file.gp ) >/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I was not aware of the subshell option... This looks like a clean solution. You're saying that the final `cd` is useless because only the subshell is affected by the initial `cd`, how does this change if the initial `cd` fails ?

Answer (score 2):

Save the return value in a variable:

```
cd some/path; gnuplot -e gnuplot_file.gp; gnuplot_ret=$?; cd "$OLDPWD"; exit $gnuplot_ret
```

Another way: Run in a subshell:

```
(cd some/path; gnuplot -e gnuplot_file.gp)
```

Since the directory change happened in a subshell, it doesn't affect your current shell and you don't need to `cd` back. And you get the exit status for free.

Answer (score 2):

You could capture the exit code in a variable:

```sh
cd some/path; gnuplot -e gnuplot_file.gp ; a=$?
```

return to the previous directory (without any console output):

```sh
cd -- "$OLDPWD"
```

#### Print exit code

And then print the exit code captured (full line):

```sh
cd some/path; gnuplot -e gnuplot_file.gp ; a=$?; cd -- "$OLDPWD"; echo "$a"
```

---

If you need to re-create an exit code, there are many possible ways:

```sh
[ "x$a" == 'x0' ]
[ "$a" -eq 0 ]
[ ! "${a#0}" ]
[[ $a == 0 ]]
[[ $a -eq 0 ]]
```

It is recommendable not to use "${a#1}" as an error exit code could be any number other than 1. It is not guaranteed that `a` will be 1 for an error.

Or, as a is a number, if you accept to use an arithmetic solution (bash):

```sh
(( a == 0 ))
! (( a ))
(( ! a ))
```

#### Re-create exit code..

The full line would be:

```sh
cd some/path; gnuplot -e gnuplot_file.gp ; a=$?; cd -- "$OLDPWD"; (( ! a ))
```

The exit code will be 0 or 1, all errors will be reported with an exit code of 1.

---

#### Full exit code

An `exit "$a"` is useful only if it is useful to end the execution of the script.
Understand that that will preserve the actual exit code.

```sh
 cd some/path && gnuplot -e gnuplot_file.gp ; a=$?; cd -- "$OLDPWD"; exit "$a"
```

A 'return "$a"' may be useful if used inside a function.

```sh
function_gnuplot(){
    cd some/path && gnuplot -e gnuplot_file.gp ; a=$?
    cd -- "$OLDPWD"; return "$a"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you well explained answer ! I sadly don't see why this answer is better than the one I got in the comments of my question. Your answer provides a nice way to return the full exit code but I don't need that much...

Comment: @PinkFloyd There are several differences: no use of (evil) eval, simple and clear IMO use of a variable to capture the exit code, explaining why `${a#1}` is wrong, and the use of bash arithmetic ((! a )). That is beside the full exit code you mention. As to which is better? Well, it is up to you to make such judgement and select the one that works better for you. In my opinion, I like mine better, but I am not the one responsible of making such call. In either case, just Enjoy what you got.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the dir in your code before calling the `system`

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char old_dir[BUFFSIZE];
  getcwd(old_dir, BUFFSIZE); 

  chdir("some/path");

  int retvalue=system("gnuplot -e gnuplot_file.gp");

  chdir(old_dir);

  if (retvalue == -4) {
    /* do something ... */
  }
}
```

Note that this solution is **not thread-safe** because changes the current directory of the process.